# Calculate exponential complex sum with fft instead of summation to simulate diffraction?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, physics, discrete

### Context

I am trying to understand x-ray diffraction a little better by coding it up in python. For a collection of points with positions R_i, the Debye formula goes

[image]

where the i in the exponential is for the complex number, all other i's are for indices and for now `b_i = b_j = 1`, for simplicity.,

Now I tried explicitly calculating this sum for a collection of points of which I have the coordinates
[image]

```
import numpy as np
# set up grid
dims = 2
side = 30
points = np.power(side, dims)
coords = np.zeros((dims, points)) 

xc, yc = np.meshgrid(np.arange(side), np.arange(side))
coords[0, :] = xc.reshape((points))
coords[1, :] = yc.reshape((points))


# calculate diffraction
xdist = np.subtract.outer(coords[0], coords[0])
ydist = np.subtract.outer(coords[1], coords[1])
rdist = np.stack((xdist, ydist))
rdist = rdist.reshape(2, rdist.shape[1]*rdist.shape[2])

qs = 200
qspace = np.stack((np.linspace(-2, 8, qs), np.zeros(qs)))
diffrac = np.sum(np.exp(-1j * np.tensordot(qspace.T, rdist, axes=1)), axis=1)
```

Which gave me the following after a couple seconds

[image]

This looks as expected (periodicity of 2 pi, as the dots have spacing 1). It also makes sense that this takes some time: for 900 points, 810000 distances have to be calculated. I don't use loops so I think the code is not that bad in terms of efficiency, but just the fact that I'm calculating this sum manually seems inherently slow.

### Thoughts

Now it looks as if things would speed up greatly if I could use a discrete fast fourier transform for this - given the shape of the sum. However:

- for the discrete fourier transform, I would still need to 'pixelate' the image (as far as I understand), to include a lot of empty space in between the points in my signal. As if I were to transform the pixels of the first image I shared. This also seems less efficient (e.g. because of the sampling).
- I would like to move points around afterwards, so the fact that the first image is a grid and thus sampled regularly is not particularly helpful. It looks as if non-uniform fourier transformations could help me, but still that would require me to 'pixelate' the image and set some values to 0.

### Question

Is there a way to use FFT (or another method) to calculate the sum faster, starting from a list of np.array coordinates (x,y)? (of dirac delta functions, if you want so...).

Specifically pointers at relevant mathematical techniques/python functions/python packages would be appreciated. I'm not that familiar using using fourier transforms for actual applications, but most of the material I find online seems irrelevant. So probably I'm looking in the wrong direction, or something's lacking in my understanding. All help is appreciated!

(the first image is a screenshot from https://www.ill.eu/fileadmin/user_upload/ILL/6_Careers/1_All_our_vacancies/PhD_recruitment/Student_Seminars/2017/19-2017-05-09_Fischer_Cookies.pdf, as it seems there's no math  notation on SO or I did not find it))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer provides a solution to make the code more efficient so it fully uses the computing power of your CPU and so to make it significantly faster.

---

More than 90% of the time is spent in `np.exp` because computing the experiential of complex numbers is very expensive.

One solution to speed this up is to use **multiple threads** (since Numpy does not use multiple threads). On top of that, we can also use a **faster implementation of `np.exp`** (typically leveraging SIMD units of the CPU). Both can be done easily with **Numexpr**.

Then, we can speed up the `np.tensordot` operation using the matrix multiplication `qspace.T @ rdist` since the Numpy implementation is not efficient.

```py
import numexpr as ne

# Equivalent of the last line of the code:
tmp1 = qspace.T @ rdist
tmp2 = ne.evaluate('exp(-1j * tmp1)')
diffrac = np.sum(tmp2, axis=1)
```

---

### Performance evaluation

Here are performance results on my i5-9600KF CPU (6 cores):

```
Initial code:         9.3 s
New proposed code:    1.1 s
```

Thus, the new implementation is **8.5 times faster**. Most of the time is still spent in computing the exponential of complex numbers (>60%).

Comment: This is very cool, thank you for the great suggestions. I learned a lot from those 4 lines of code... I'll leave this open a little longer to see if anyone can add to this or give a good reason why the fourier transform does not work here, but if nothing else comes up by monday this'll be the answer!